# SQL Server Reporting Services report parameter is not defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a report with SQL Server Reporting Services so I put the url directly  in the browser but I get this error:

> have attempted to establish a report parameter 'report parameter' which is not defined in this report

but if I open the report with Visual Studio and click in preview and pass the parameters I'm able to see the report without any problem.

Comment: cross check the `report parameter` name . is that same binding ?

Comment: You need to make sure that the parameter name from report and and from the code are same

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure report parameter name from the report is same in your code.
[image]